# 'Building Workspace' has encountered a prob, info cannot be null

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I was programming an SWT application, when suddenly appeared this message. I searched the web but the problem was frequently related to android development...

I noticed the problem is caused by this function:

```
private static int writeCharacter(String p)
    {
        switch(p)
        {
        case "\\x0000":
            return 0x0000;
        case "\\x0001":
            return 0x0001;
        case "ぁ":
            return 0x0002;
        case "あ":
            return 0x0003;
        case "ぃ":
            return 0x0004;
        case "い":
            return 0x0005;
        case "ぅ":
            return 0x0006;
        ...
        default:
            return 0x0000;
        }
    }
```

(The ... stands for many many other entries)

What's wrong, I'm using Eclipse 4.3 under Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit?

EDIT: I updated Eclipse from 4.3 to 4.4, but the problem still exists...
I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Check the Error Log view for details on the failure, or at least the stack trace.

Comment: It says "Info cannot be null!", but nothing specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I searched the web and it seems a common bug related to eclipse and NOT the java code...

I solved it by converting from switch to a mega if-else if-else

```
private static int writeCharacter(String p)
    {
        if(p== "\\x0000")
            return 0x0000;
        else if(p== "\\x0001")
            return 0x0001;
        else if(p== "ぁ")
            return 0x0002;
        else if(p== "あ")
            return 0x0003;
        else if(p== "ぃ")
            return 0x0004;
        else if(p== "い")
            return 0x0005;
        else if(p== "ぅ")
            return 0x0006;
        ...
        else
            return 0x0000;
    }
```

I hope this can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem which should be an eclipse bug according to [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410892).
Should be fixed with eclipse 4.5 but upgrading to this version did not help for me.

I boiled the compiling problem down to this line of code

```
IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(im, null, pngmeta);
```

When commented, eclipse builds correctly.